# XML String into PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I feel like I'm going crazy. I need to take a string of text from an xml file, and define it as a PHP variable and output it into an HTML page. I can't figure out why this wont work. Any ideas??

I have this xml document (people.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<datas>
 <person>
  <people>
   <owner>Joe Blow</owner>
  </people>
 </person>
</datas>
```

This PHP (db.php):

```
<?php 


$xml = simplexml_load_file('people.xml')

or die("Error: Can't load people");

$xml->person->people->owner = $owner;


?>
```

This HTML(index.php):

```
<?php include 'db.php';?>

<label for="owner-1"><?php echo $owner ?></label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming everything else is right / Based on the code you have shown,

```
$xml->person->people->owner = $owner;
```

should be

```
$owner = $xml->person->people->owner;
```

You are trying to assign the value of `$owner` to `$xml->person->people->owner`
It should be the other way round.

Comment: 10 seconds later...i was going to post the same xD

Comment: @RobertRozas Happens to me all the time :)